# Connecting WSO2 BPS to ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm new to WSO2 products,
Currently I'm deploying 2 instance of WSO2 products, those are: ESB & BPS,

According to this article [here](http://wso2.com/blogs/architecture/2012/01/bus-architecture-to-handle-inbound-and-outbound-calls-with-bpel/), we can expose BPS service as an endpoint in ESB.

My question is: how to make my BPS service exposed as an endpoint in my ESB? through the use of web management GUI off course!

Thanks in advance,
Bromo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy a process in WSO2 BPS, a process published web service will also be available. In order to expose this BPS service on ESB, you need to create a proxy service from ESB. Then for the target endpoint address, specify the bps service.

You can find sample from here.

http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/proxy_samples.html